# combining two or more querysets from different models in django

Tags: django

**Main model:**

```
 class MainCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
```

**App#1:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    main_category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, default=1, related_name='car_category')
```

**App#2:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)    
    main_category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, default=1, related_name='classifieds_category')
```

on home page I want a combined list of both category list items as follows.

```
{% for object in main_cat_list %}
{{ object.title }}
{% for item in object.car_category %} 
{{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How I can insert classifieds category also inside this list?

Comment: Well you're already iterating over `object.car_category`, why can't you also iterate over `object.classifieds_category`?

Comment: It was actually not falling under the main category due to my html, I corrected it now, Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you merely want to also display the classified_category as you have the car_category.

```
{% for object in main_cat_list %}
{{ object.title }}
{% for item in object.car_category %} 
{{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% for item in object.classified_category %} 
{{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```